# Looping Simple JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

For some reason my loop is treating this array as a string and looping through each character.

Here's the structure:

```
var json = [
    {
        "featured": "1",
        "href": "someurl/",
        "property": "some property",
        "location": "<strong>Winston-Salem</strong>North Carolina, United States",
        "date": "23 Oct",
        "year": "2014"
    },
    {
        "featured": "1",
        "href": "someurl/",
        "property": "Sheraton Albuquerque Airport Hotel",
        "location": "<strong>Albuquerque</strong>New Mexico, United States",
        "date": "23 Oct",
        "year": "2014"
     }
    ]
```

I'm looping it with:

```
    for(var i = 0; i <= json.length; i++) {
        console.log(json[i]);
    }
```

Here's a snippet of the type of output I get:

> ```
> f
> e
> a 
> t 
> u 
> r 
> e 
> d 
> " 
> : 
> " 
> 1
> "
> ```

Comment: Probably it *is* a string. Fetching JSON from a server doesn't magically convert it, you need to call a json library (or eval, if you must). For further diagnosis, what does "typeof(json)" yield?

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question but the for loop condition should be `i < json.length`

Comment: Where is `json` defined, in a script element or is it data from an ajax response?

Answer (score 1):

Json is actually a string while you havent serialized it. So it is a string representation of arrays lists and other objects.

If it is an ajax response maybe you have a wrong mime type. So it thinks it is getting a raw string rather than json.

If you are asking such a question I think you probably should read this first [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Edit:

If you want to get correct answer you should clarify your question. For example what are you using to get json.
If it is jQuery than you shuld use something like this:

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
var items = [];
$.each( data, function( key, val ) {
items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
});
$( "<ul/>", {
"class": "my-new-list",
html: items.join( "" )
}).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

[took it from here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

or if you are using pure js you should manually serialize json like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

[took it from here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp)

where text variable contains string got from the server or wherever you get it from.

Comment: Setting a `content-type` header won't help. Parsing it with [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) will.